# Missing one rooftop race

Tags: crackdown-3

I've been around the map and I'm missing one rooftop race but I have no idea where it is. I have the one at the top of the Science Center. Are there any other commonly overlooked rooftop races that do not easily display on the overview map?

Answer (score -1):

Look for "astest way down" in "the vision" area of the map near the south. Thats what I was missing.

Comment: Is "astest way down" a typo for "Fastest way down"?